# Displaying the right picture associated with a dynamically created thumbnail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

Have been working on this for too long now. Before I get loads of answers suggesting image gallery scripts I wanted to learn how this works for myself. I have created a thumbnail gallery dynamically with `ajax` and `php`, the only thing I cannot get quite right is when the thumbnail is clicked the full size image displays in the pop up box. Without the `jquery` to disable the default link action the corret image displays in a new tab, so I know the dynamically created code is ok. I have set my code to get the `href` attribute of the dynamic link and there I think I'm having the issue, I can get ony one image to show no matter the thumbnail clicked on

**Code that creates the thumbnail**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {//READY FUNC

$(".albumName").click(function(){//click
     var albumid = this.id;
     $('#imageFrame').empty();
     $.post("includes/viewgallery.php",{albumId:albumid},function(data)  {//json
        console.log(data);  
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           $.each(data, function(key, val) {//iterate each data

               var albumName = val.albumName;
               var photoId = val.photoId;
               var photoName = val.photoName;
               var photoUrl = val.photoUrl;
               var thumbId = val.thumbId;
               var thumbName = val.thumbName;
               var thumbnailUrl = val.thumbnailUrl;
               var href = "http://217.199.187.191/mandingaarts.co.uk";

               $('#imageFrame').append('<a id"'+photoId+'" class="lightBox" href="'+href+'' +photoUrl+ '"><img id"'+thumbId+'" class="thumbnail" src="'+href+'' +thumbnailUrl+ '"/></a>'); 

              })//iterate each data

         });//json

    });//click

});//READY FUNC
</script>
```

**The code that gets the fullsize image and displays it in popup box**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#imageFrame').on('click', '.thumbnail', function(e)
{

    e.preventDefault()
    var a_href = $('.lightBox').prop('href');
    console.log(a_href)
    $('#lightboxImage').prop('src', a_href)
$("#faded").fadeToggle("scale");
});

$('#lightbox').on('click', '#closeLightbox', function() {
    $('#faded').fadeToggle("scale")
    $('#lightboxImage').prop('src', '#')
});

</script>
```

Comment: in html you are getting correct href for all thumbnails?

Comment: @ saqibahmad Yes as I stated without the  e.preventefault code the links open up the correct images

Comment: can you add generated html so we can play with this to get the answer

Comment: follow the Kris Zani answer i think he is right you are refrencing to wrong object and always get first element of the .thumbnail class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are appending a lot of anchors into the #imageFrame div.  each of those anchors has a class of lightBox.

then on click you are retreiving the array of all elements with a class of lightbox and getting the href property of one of them - probably the first element.

since the onlick is the image try something like

a_href = $(this).parent().prop('href');

Comment: I wondered if the $(this) would be used somewhere, and I never even considered the .parent, but that has sorted it, Many Thanks

Comment: remember console.log can show you lots more than just simple values.  if you had done console.log( $('.lightBox') ), you would have seen that it returns an array.  good luck and happy coding.